# How to perform a Mongoose validate function only for create user page and not edit user page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Background**

I am currently building a website with Node.js, Express, and MongoDB. I am using mongoose to work with my MongoDB server. 
Right now I have a function in my Mongoose schema that checks to see if a user's inputed email address already exists in the DB. I want this function to only get called on the create account page. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**The Problem**

The function works great but it is getting called on the edit user profile page as well as the create user page. This means that if a user doesn't change their email on the edit profile page, they can't update their profile. I only want this validate unique email function to be called for the create user page so I can avoid this problem. How do I run a function depending on the page the user is on?

**The Code**

 
*Function in my User Schema to check if email already exists*

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(function(value, done) {
    this.model('User').count({ email: value }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } 
        // If `count` is greater than zero, "invalidate"
        done(!count);
    });
}, 'Email already exists');
```

*Entire User Schema (filename is user.server.model.js)*

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * A Validation function for local strategy properties
 */
var validateLocalStrategyProperty = function(property) {
    return ((this.provider !== 'local' && !this.updated) || property.length);
};

/**
 * A Validation function for local strategy password
 */
var validateLocalStrategyPassword = function(password) {
    return (this.provider !== 'local' || (password && password.length > 6));
};

/**
 * User Schema
 */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    companyName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    companyWebsite: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    companyAddress1: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    companyAddress2: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    companyCity: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    companyState: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    companyZip: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        unique: true,
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
        match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: 'testing error message',
        required: 'Please fill in a username',
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, 'Password should be longer']
    },
    salt: {
        type: String
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Provider is required'
    },
    providerData: {},
    additionalProvidersData: {},
    roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['user', 'admin']
        }],
        default: ['user']
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    /* For reset password */
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: String
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: Date
    }
});

/**
 * Hook a pre save method to hash the password
 */
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.password && this.password.length > 6) {
        this.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
        this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
    }

    next();
});

/**
 * Check if email already exists in database
 */
UserSchema.path('email').validate(function(value, done) {
    this.model('User').count({ email: value }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } 
        // If `count` is greater than zero, "invalidate"
        done(!count);
    });
}, 'Email already exists');

/**
 * Create instance method for hashing a password
 */
UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
    if (this.salt && password) {
        return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
    } else {
        return password;
    }
};

/**
 * Create instance method for authenticating user
 */
UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {
    return this.password === this.hashPassword(password);
};

/**
 * Find possible not used username
 */
UserSchema.statics.findUniqueUsername = function(username, suffix, callback) {
    var _this = this;
    var possibleUsername = username + (suffix || '');

    _this.findOne({
        username: possibleUsername
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (!err) {
            if (!user) {
                callback(possibleUsername);
            } else {
                return _this.findUniqueUsername(username, (suffix || 0) + 1, callback);
            }
        } else {
            callback(null);
        }
    });
};

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

*users.server.routes.js file*

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(app) {
    // User Routes
    var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');

    // Setting up the users profile api
    app.route('/users/me').get(users.me);
    app.route('/users').put(users.update);
    app.route('/users/accounts').delete(users.removeOAuthProvider);

    // Setting up the users password api
    app.route('/users/password').post(users.changePassword);
    app.route('/auth/forgot').post(users.forgot);
    app.route('/auth/reset/:token').get(users.validateResetToken);
    app.route('/auth/reset/:token').post(users.reset);

    // Setting up the users authentication api
    app.route('/auth/signup').post(users.signup);
    app.route('/auth/signin').post(users.signin);
    app.route('/auth/signout').get(users.signout);

    // Finish by binding the user middleware
    app.param('userId', users.userByID);
};
```

Comment: Could you post the code where it's getting called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than you to Andrew Lavers. I think his answer would have worked fine but what I ended up doing was simply using the unique index validation on my email in the schema.

```
email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
    match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
    unique: 'testing error message'
},
```

The mean.js boiler plate code has a controller in the server called errors.server.controller.js which handles errors that appear when unique index validation fails (they give error codes 11000 and 11001).

```
exports.getErrorMessage = function(err) {
    var message = '';

    if (err.code) {
        switch (err.code) {
            case 11000:
            case 11001:
                message = getUniqueErrorMessage(err);
                break;
            default:
                message = 'Something went wrong';
        }
    } else {
        for (var errName in err.errors) {
            if (err.errors[errName].message) message = err.errors[errName].message;
        }
    }

    return message;
};
```

When I used the unique index validation instead I did not have any problems on the edit profile page. 

I tried the unique property before and it didn't work, I found out this is because if there are already duplicate values in your database you have to delete all the information in your database. I heard there are other ways of solving this problem but for me it was easiest to delete the database. 
The unique validation index approach is the recommended approach by Mongoose creator Aaron Heckmann to avoid un-expected race condition related errors faced when using other approaches.
See http://nraj.tumblr.com/post/38706353543/handling-uniqueness-validation-in-mongo-mongoose

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Document.isNew` flag to only run your check on creation. Like this:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.isNew) {
        // Enforce constraints here
    }

    if (this.password && this.password.length > 6) {
        this.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
        this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
    }

    next();
});
```

You also have `Document.isModified` at your disposal, so in your save hook you could check `this.isModified('email')` as well.

Comment: Can I copy and paste the UserSchema.path('email').validate code directly into that if this.isNew block?